# Get location function based on GPS. WinMobile 6.5 Platform

Tags: windows, vb.net, mobile, gps, windows-mobile-gps

I am writing a windows mobile application based on GPS technology. everything is ready but I need the function which is used to retrieve GPS location coordinates (latitude and longitude).

I declared latitude and longitude, but now I need the function of GPS to put it inside a button I created, get longitude and latitude values and save them.

Environement:
Windows Mobile 6.5
Framework 6.5, Professional

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The GPS Intermediate Driver provides a very simple-to-use API for providing shared access to GPS data. You can use [GPSGetPosition()](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DHa9NkeD7l4J:msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202050.aspx) for you purpose. There is an example how to use it in this article, [Using the GPS Intermediate Driver from Native Code](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mYz_P_MLh3MJ:msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158597.aspx).

#### See Also:

- [GPS Programming Tips for Windows Mobile](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?hl=en&biw=1024&bih=581&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.com%2Fraffael%2Farchive%2F2008%2F03%2F25%2Fgps-programming-tips-for-windows-mobile-part-1.aspx)
- [Use GPS And Web Maps For Location-Aware Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315419.aspx)
- [GPS Intermediate Driver for Windows Mobile](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:3UpnNjzmH74J:dalelane.co.uk/blog/%3Fp%3D296)
- [GPS Intermediate Driver](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:iVqGbhvbuzEJ:msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202086.aspx)
- [Using the GPS Intermediate Driver from Managed Code](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vXcLK5e2GIAJ:msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158708.aspx)

Comment: this all looks like c++ - is there a c# way to do it?